# Regex match double quote, but not pair of double quotes

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression to match (and ultimately capture, replace, and escape) `"`, but not `".*"`, and can't seem to figure it out.

How to match the singular quote, and not the set of them?

Comment: So really you need to add a {1} after your regex, I think that should be able to capture just one double-quote..

Comment: "_How to match the pair of quotes, and not the singular?_" Doesn't this contradict with your title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the expression you need is something like this:

```
^([^"]*?)(")([^"]*?)$
```

Please see example here: http://www.regexr.com/39qf4

Answer (score 2):

This will match pairs of double quotes, skips them and attempts to find single quotes that aren't skipped.

```regex
".*?"(*SKIP)(*F)|"
```

Here is a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/vF9iJ5/1).

Comment: Problem with matching single quotes is that it heavily depends on the context (or other rules, like: is the space before or after the quote). In your answer you assumed that an unmatched quote is always after a pair of quotes but it may not be a case: "It is 2" long". So without some more details from OP we can only guess.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for lines with only one quote, this would work.

```
^[^"]*"[^"]*$
```

Translation: any number of characters that are not double quotes followed by one double quote followed by any number of characters that are not double quotes

Answer (score 0):

Seems as though I had the same problem.
Came up with this solution: `(?<!")"(?!")`

Meaning: matches a double quote that is neither followed by a double quote nor preceded by a double quote.

Comment: This is working for successive quote, but it matches `"blah"` that is not wanted.

Comment: There are other answers (and a accepted one) that provide the OP's question, and they were posted some time ago. When posting an answer [see: How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), please make sure you add either a new solution, or a substantially better explanation, especially when answering older questions.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your comment, @Toto.
Regex suggested by me doesn't match "blah" as a whole string. It matches each double quote separately, without blah.
Here's a [link](https://regex101.com/), where I checked it out.
Not to mention that it worked for me in the project, where such task appeared.

As for what is wanted. As I understood the initial question from user2402831, the desired result was to be able to match a double quote and not the string encapsulated by double quotes.
My answer seems to provide that result.

So, please, can you elaborate on what you meant?