# Regex: Match double quote that is not closed

Tags: .net, regex

I want to match all double quotes that are not closed.

Basically get me the last double quote if there is an oneven amount of double quotes or do not match anything if there is an even amount of double quotes.

Consider this magnificent code block:

```
Input -> Match?
===============
"testy" --> NO MATCH
"ack... --> Match "
"oh my" and "oy my" and " pp --> Match last "
do match " this --> Match "
more "testy" "test --> Match last "
more "testy" test --> NO MATCH
```

The answers here didn't work:
[Regex match double quote, but not pair of double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26619242/regex-match-double-quote-but-not-pair-of-double-quotes)
Most promising there was: `".*?"(*SKIP)(*F)|"` but that doesn't work for .NET.

I know a non-regex is possible here but I'm curious about how it can be done...

My implementation without Regex - which is ok I guess:

```
if (searchText.IndexOf('"') > -1)
{
    int quoteCount = searchText.Count(x => x == '"');
    if (quoteCount % 2 != 0)
    {
        searchText = searchText.Insert(searchText.LastIndexOf('"'), "\\");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about something as "simple" as

```
^[^\"]*(\"[^\"]*\"[^\"]*)*(\")[^\"]*$
```

I only tested it against "classic" regex interpreter and it doesn't use any bizzare tricks, so it should be fully compatible regardless the platform.

What it does is basically:

1. Match the beginning of the string (line)
2. Match any (may be 0) number of non-" characters
3. Match any (may be 0) number of times:

   - " character
   - any number of non-" characters
   - " character
   - any number of non-" characters
4. Match the " character (this will be the group you are looking for)
5. Match any number of non-" characters
6. Match the end of the string

Answer (score 2):

.NET has variable-length lookbehinds you can leverage.

```
(?<=^(?>(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*)"(?=[^"]*?$)
```

[Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%5e(%3f%3e(%3f%3a%5b%5e%22%5cn%5d*%22)%7b2%7d)*%5b%5e%22%5cn%5d*)%22(%3f%3d%5b%5e%22%5cn%5d*%3f%24)&i=%22testy%22%0d%0a%22ack...%0d%0a%22oh+my%22+and+%22oy+my%22+and+%22+pp%0d%0ado+match+%22+this%0d%0amore+%22testy%22+%22test%0d%0amore+%22testy%22+test%0d%0a&o=m)

For the sake of demo, I've replaced the `[^"]` with `[^"\n]` to consider each line independently.

Here's the idea:

- Match `"`
- Make sure it's the last one: `(?=[^"]*?$)`
- Make sure it's preceded by an even number of `"`: `(?<=^(?>(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*)`
  Reading that backwards (matching is done backwards in a .NET lookbehind), we get:

  - `[^"]*`
  - Then match `[^"]*"` an even number of times (`{2}`)
  - Then match the start of the string `^`

The atomic group prevents catastrophic backtracking.